# Having trouble setting up my Mocha testing environment using node.js framework with M1 chip for iOS

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, apple-m1

So every time I open VSC and try to run yarn, the version of node is `node -v = 18.3.0`
I'm not super good at understanding bash or the iOS FS, but *this* is the work around that fixes my nvm and presents me with the correct version I need so I can use `node use 14.15.1`

**Workaround**

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"

[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"
```

I assume this is a pathing issue when I installed nvm/npm. I'm trying to document this for my team so they don't run into this issue in the future.

[This is what I get when opening VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ctrz.png)

Comment: Let me know if I can provide any paths or documentation to clarify! This is my first question on SO so go easy on me :P